# Access constants from super module within included modules (config())

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-bootstrap

I have a global module 'app' which include two other modules 'app.core' and 'app.service'. This is basic settings. Inside the two sub module I can access the constant from both two modules. However I cannot access constants declared in 'app' within 'app.core' or 'app.service'.

Also I use angular.bootstrap to delay my initialization because I need to retrieve a config from server. But after receiving the config I do angular.module('app').constant('config', config); So the constant should be well defined..

LAst point, inside the 'app' module config I can access the config constant.

Any idea ?

'app' module constants declaration

```
angular.module('app',[
    'app.core',
    'app.service'
])
    .module('app')
    .constant('foo', 'foo')
```

'app.core' constants

```
    angular
    .module('app.core')
    .constant('core', 'core');
```

In 'app.service' I can get core constant

```
    angular.module('app.services',[]).config(function($injector){
        console.log($injector.get('core'));
    })
```

But I cannot retrieve 'app' constant

```
angular.module('app.services',[]).config(function($injector){
        console.log($injector.get('foo'));
    })
```

Will crash

Comment: angular.module('app.services',[]).config(function($injector, 'foo'){
        console.log($injector.get('foo'));
    }), perhaps?

Comment: If I'm not wrong $injector is a way to access directly injected components instead of declare it inside function declaration. So it's the same way and doesn't work unfortunatly. By the way I didn't understand what you are really meaning, are you writing string inside function declaration ?

Comment: Sorry, it was supposed to be without single quotes. I think scarlz's answer is on the right track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both configurations you are trying to access a constant defined within a separate module, but then not defining that module as a dependency. How, for example, can `app.services` have access to `foo` when `foo` is defined on a module which *requires* `app.services` in the first place?

The reason that `core` is available to `app.services` despite this is because you have listed the dependencies in such an order when defining `app` that angular happens to have loaded `app.core` prior to `app.services`. The order of the defined dependencies, however, should not matter.

In order to correct this, you should consider refactoring your modules so that there is no inherent circular dependency. For example, consider making your config a module in itself and inject it into the dependent services:

```
angular.module('app', ['app.core', 'app.services'])

angular.module('app.config', [])
  .constant('foo', 'foo')

angular.module('app.core', ['app.config'])
  .config(function(foo) {})

angular.module('app.services', ['app.config'])
  .config(function(foo) {})
```

Note also that using the injector to get constants is un-necessary as they can be injected directly during the configuration stage.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works well if I use another module for the config. However I have another question, I'm now wondering why app.service can access app.Core constant and vice versa ? I mean they are not including each other right ?

Comment: This is what is meant by my second paragraph – the `app.core` constant is available through virtue of having been loaded already as the first dependency of `app`. This can be demonstrated by swapping the dependency order for `app`, as you would then see an error.

Comment: Yes I was confusing on this point but thanks to you it's clear now ;).